# Modular inverse: why am I allowed to use the formula :$a^{-1}\mod p \equiv a^{p-2}\mod p$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

Why am I allowed to do this? Do you have a reference? 
$$a^{-1}\mod p \equiv a^{p-2}\mod p$$
Where do I get this? From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52595329/elliptic-curve-double-and-add-implementation-in-python)

```
m = (Q_y - N_y) * pow((Q_x-N_x), p-2, p)
```

It is point addition in EC (calculating the slope).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) says $a^{p-1}\equiv1\bmod p$ if $\gcd(a,p)=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), if $p$ does not divide $a$, then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p$.

Again, if $p$ does not divide $a$, we can multiply both sides by $a^{-1}$ to get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you. But does that mean that my formula is incorrect?

Comment: Your formula is correct:  $a^{p-1}\equiv1\bmod p$, so $a^{p-1}a^{-1}\equiv a^{-1}\bmod p$, so $a^{p-2}\equiv a^{-1}\bmod p$

Answer (score 0):

Notice $a^{p-1} = a*a^{p-2}$ (assuming $p-1 > 0$)

So if $a^{-1}$ exists then

$a^{-1}*a^{p-1} \equiv a^{-1}(a*a^{p-2})\equiv (a^{-1}*a)a^{p-2}\equiv 1*a^{p-2}\equiv a^{p-2}\pmod p$.

But $a^{-1}$ can only exist if $\gcd(a,p) = 1$.

Now Fermat's little Theorem states.  If $p$ is prime and if $\gcd(a,p) = 1$ then

> $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$>

So.......

$a^{-1} \equiv a^{-1}*1 \equiv a^{-1}*a^{p-1}\equiv a^{-1}*a*a^{p-2}\equiv 1*a^{p-2}\equiv a^{p-2}\pmod p$.

That's all.